# Can .findall() match multiple values in python etree?

Tags: python, xml.etree

Is there a way to match multiple elements in a tree using `.findall()`?

I would like to do this:

```
trees = log.findall('element1' or 'element2')
```

This is my work around (which works in my case because I don't have both e1 and e2 in the same XML):

```
trees = log.findall('element1')
if not trees:
    trees = log.findall('element2')
```

I am parsing XML files that have similar structures but different names. C# allows "element1 | element2" matching.

Comment: Given your workaround, what if there are elements in both element1 and element2?

Comment: Good point. I edited to question to be more clear. I'm boiler plating code that works either with 1 or 2, never both.

Comment: @user3769076: Can you require `lxml` and use `lxml.etree` in place of the stdlib `xml.etree`? It often works as a drop-in replacement, and it offers a better answer here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can't. C# appears to be using XPath expressions, but the [ElementTree XPath support for XPath queries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) is too limited and does not include the support for this.

You can use `or` to pick your second search if the first is empty:

```
trees = log.findall('element1') or log.findall('element2')
```

because an empty result is false-y.

The alternative is to use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de), an ElementTree API implementation on top of `libxml2`, which [supports all of the XPath 1.0 spec](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath). Then you can do:

```
log.xpath('(.//element1|.//element2)')
```

Comment: Does the `lxml` implementation of the etree API support `|` in XPath? If so, that may be an acceptable alternative for the OP.

Comment: @abarnert: `lxml` supports all of XPath 1.0.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just not sure whether it has full XPath in its etree `findall` or not (and for some reason it's not building on the machine I'm sitting at, so I can't test…).

Comment: @abarnert: no, `.xpath()` is the method to use here; `.findall()` was kept bug-compatible with the original API implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find out from the webpage or any other explanation that you could use (a|b) with xpath. The documentation is horrible although lxml is one of the best tools.

Comment: FWIW, I had to use the XPath syntax `.xpath("//element1|//element2')`. I couldn't get `lxml` to accept the `//(element1|element2)` pattern,.

Comment: @TomJohnson: ah, yes, that's my mistake. XPath 1.0 doesn't support `|` unions between relative location paths (the `element1` and `element2` strings), only between path expressions (which includes the `//` prefix). I'll correct my answer.