# get the child element of from the xml

Tags: python

I have an XML where I want to get the child elements of the elements where my condition is satisfied.

```
 <hashTree/>
      <ConfigTestElement guiclass="HttpDefaultsGui" testclass="ConfigTestElement" testname="HTTP Request Defaults" enabled="true">
        <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
          <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">https</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.concurrentPool">6</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
      </ConfigTestElement>
      <hashTree/>
      <CacheManager guiclass="CacheManagerGui" testclass="CacheManager" testname="HTTP Cache Manager" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="useExpires">true</boolProp>
      </CacheManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="HTTP Cookie Manager" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
        <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">true</boolProp>
      </CookieManager>
      <hashTree/>
      <kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroup guiclass="kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroupGui" testclass="kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroup" testname="/v1/language-preferences__GET" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">startnextloop</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Threads initial delay">0</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Start users count">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Start users count burst">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Start users period">75</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Stop users count">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Stop users period">75</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="flighttime">3600</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="rampUp">75</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
          <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
        </elementProp>
      </kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
```

above I want to get the value of `<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">2</stringProp>` which is the chile element of `kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroup` also attribute `@enabled="true"`.

I can filter out the required elements with the below code.

```
tree = ET.parse(xml_path)
active_threads = tree.findall('.//kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroup[@enabled="true"]' or './/ThreadGroup[@enabled="true"]')
```

now I want to iterate within the each thread from the `active_threads` and get the child elements.
something like

```
    for active_thread in active_threads:
        thread_name.append(active_thread.attrib['testname'])
        for child in thread.getchildren():
            print(child['@name'])
            # <print the value as well against each child like for "ThreadGroup.num_threads" is 2 >
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ElementTree - iterate through child nodes and text in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174152/python-elementtree-iterate-through-child-nodes-and-text-in-order)

Answer (score 1):

#### Looping through children

You can loop through childrens in a ElementTree's Element like so:

```py
for child in element:
   ...
```

[ElementTree docs's Parsing XML](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)

In this case, you can do:

```py
for active_thread in active_threads:
    for child in active_thread:
        print(child.attrib['name'])
```

#### Also a NOTE about the OR operator:

OR is a short-circuit operator. It chooses A if true, then A else B. [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

In your circumstance, it will only provide `.//kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroup[@enabled="true"]` to `tree.findall` instead of including `.//ThreadGroup[@enabled="true"]`.

Plus, Python's ElementTree is limited enough that you cannot include 2 tags in an XPATH query. Instead, this works if you want to provide one of the other:

```py
active_threads = tree.findall('.//kg.apc.jmeter.threads.SteppingThreadGroup[@enabled="true"]') or tree.findall('.//ThreadGroup[@enabled="true"]')
```

[StackOverflow question on catching many tags in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871372/8075127)

Comment: This is working. Thank you and wish you a happy new year!